# Oracle Identity columns system generated sequence life cycle

Tags: oracle, sequence, identity

I created a table with identity column and which created system generated sequence. On dropping the table which is not dropping the sequence. When the system generated sequence will be dropped? Please help to understand.

```
SELECT object_name, object_type
FROM   user_objects where object_type ='SEQUENCE'

CREATE TABLE identity_test_tab (
  id          NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  description VARCHAR2(30)
);

which created system generated sequence ISEQ$$_131916100

drop table identity_test_tab;
```

Comment: Please specify the Oracle version. It's not reproducible in 18c. See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=56e31da33ba79d98f00b8c7614aee87d)

Comment: @astentx You are not checking the `USER_OBJECTS` table after dropping the table. If you do then you will see that the sequence still exists. The solution (as per the linked duplicate) is to purge the table from the recycle bin [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ffac25847328de7977f760e7e72a98b9)

Comment: @MT0 Thank you, my comment was a very odd mistake.

Answer (score -1):

If you drop table, SEQUENCE won't get dropped. You need to dropped it separately.

```
Drop sequence sequence_name;
```

The above command give you error. You can use.

```
purge recyclebin;
```

**Second Answer**

You can find these kinds of Identity sequence with below query.

```
SELECT *
FROM   user_objects where object_type ='SEQUENCE' and generated='Y' order by last_ddl_time desc;
```

Comment: How would you find the name of the sequence?